# How to use a text file containing list of files as input for cat Linux command?

Tags: linux, cat

I would like to use the cat command to concatenate multiple files located in different folders. I have a text file containing the name and location (path) of each file as a long list  (e.g. filesLocationNames.txt), and would like to use it as an input for the cat command. 
I tried: 'cat filesLocationNames.txt | cat * > output.txt'
but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

How about `cat filesLocationNames.txt | xargs cat > output.txt`

Comment: [congrats](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html), and it doesn't work for filenames that contain spaces. `xargs < filesLocationNames.txt -d '\n' cat` would be a bit better. Or perhaps `xargs -a filesLocationNames.txt ...`

Answer (score 1):

*cat* will pipe input to output, so piping the names in won't work.  You need to supply the filenames as arguments to *cat*. E.g.:

```
cat `cat filesLocationNames.txt`
```

But that has the same problem with spaces in filenames/pathnames...

In TCSH you can try:

```
cat "'cat filesLocationNames.txt'"
```

That is doublequote (") backquote (') at the start. (No space between them!)  But it will handle spaces in the names...

Also, in TCSH:

```
foreach FILE ( "`cat filesLocationNames.txt`" )
    echo $FILE
end
```

Will handle spaces in the names...

---

Only one catch: If *filesLocationNames.txt* is too long, it will exceed the line buffer and you'll need *xargs*.  How big is it?